# System.Web.HttpContext.Current does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get some info about my users in asp.net mvc application with visual studio 2015.

When i try to to get info from request with

```
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current req = new System.Web.HttpContext.Current();
```

I get an error `Error   CS0426  The type name 'Current' does not exist in the type 'HttpContext'`

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `Current` is a property, not a method.

Comment: ...a static property, not a type.

Comment: `var req = new System.Web.HttpContext.Current;`

Comment: and the Type should be HttpContext

Comment: Uh no, how can I do `var req = new System.Web.HttpContext.Current` if the ENTIRE problem is that current doesn't seem to exist?!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get the current context

```
System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
```

If you want to create one (for some reason, like test)

```
System.Web.HttpContext newContext = new System.Web.HttpContext(
    new System.Web.HttpRequest("", "http://example.com", ""),
    new System.Web.HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter())
    );
```

Comment: Uh, no, not the answer. Impossible since Current doesn't exist in HttpContext for whatever unfathomable reason. So you can't just go `System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current` because current doesn't exist. I have no idea why it doesn't exist, and that is the problem here.

Comment: This worked for me when attempting to get the base URL in an MVC controller action.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `System.Web` reference to your project and it'll be ok.

`using System.Web;` does not generate an error even if the reference does not exist.